# SetLayeredWindowAttributes() causes mouse clicks to go through after minimizing window | WinAPI

Tags: c, windows, user-interface, winapi, gcc

Here is a [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USBUm.gif) showing my problem.
As you can see after minimizing I am not able to press anything on the window besides that one pixel sweet spot.

How can I fix this? I am compiling through MinGW using a manifest file which supports transparency through all windows versions, and I link the file too(Here is the makefile code -> https://pastebin.com/yv5HqWBM).
The reason I use a manifest file is because I need to use extended styles on child windows and that's the way it should be done from what I have found out.
Here is the manifest file -> https://pastebin.com/1RbcK3t7
Here is my code's WM_CREATE function(full code --> https://pastebin.com/s2NGh2CB ):

```
case WM_CREATE:
        SetWindowLongA(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLongA(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, RGB(255, 0, 0), 0 /*doesn't matter*/, LWA_COLORKEY);
        hbackground = CreateWindowExA(0,
                                      "STATIC",
                                      NULL,
                                      WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_BITMAP,
                                      0,
                                      0,
                                      window_width,
                                      window_height,
                                      hwnd,
                                      NULL,
                                      NULL,
                                      (LPVOID)NULL);
        setImage(hbackground, background_image_name, monitor_dimension.width, monitor_dimension.height);
        SetWindowLongA(hbackground, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLongA(hbackground, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hbackground, 0, (255 * 50) / 100, LWA_ALPHA);
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hbackground, 0, (255 * 50) / 100, LWA_ALPHA);
        break;
```

Edit - if I don't use the manifest file, this doesn't happen but then I can't use transparency on the child windows
Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: According to my test, the Windows8 and later application compatibility in the manifest make the difference and I have escalated this.