# Win32 - Make part of window a translucent while another part opaque?

Tags: c, windows, user-interface, winapi

I want one part of a window to display an image with a certain opacity while the other part to work as normal. Both parts shouldn't pass clicks through.
I have tried making the main window a certain colour then using SetLayeredWindowAttributes to make that colour transparent(so only the client area is transparent). Then having a child window over it with my translucent image. However the clicks pass through the window(even though I don't have WS_EX_TRANSPARENT). Alphablend doesn't seem to works since the bitmap isn't 32bmp. So now I am trying to use updatelayeredwindows but I am having trouble setting the region to update it.

```
    case WM_CREATE:
        hbmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImageA(NULL, "courtyard.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 1920, 1080, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
        HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
        HBITMAP hbmp_old = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdc, hbmp);

        POINT dcOffset = {0, 0};
        SIZE size = {600, 395};
        BLENDFUNCTION bf = {AC_SRC_OVER, 0, 100, 0};
        RECT wrect;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &wrect);
        wrect.top = wrect.top + 43;
      
        UPDATELAYEREDWINDOWINFO info = {sizeof(info), GetDC(NULL), NULL, &size, hdc, &dcOffset, 0, &bf, ULW_ALPHA, &wrect};
        UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect(hwnd, &info);

        SelectObject(hdc, hbmp_old);
        DeleteDC(hdc);
        DeleteObject(hbmp);
        
        HWND hbutton = CreateWindowExA(0,
                                     "BUTTON",
                                     "X",
                                     WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_FLAT,
                                     10,
                                     10,
                                     100,
                                     100,
                                     hwnd,
                                     (HMENU)NULL,
                                     NULL,
                                     (LPVOID)NULL);
        break;
```

The parts out of wrect are just a black translucent colour.
Here is my main window:

```
    hwnd = CreateWindowExA(WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_EX_LAYERED,
                           window_name,
                           window_title,
                           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                           (monitor_dimension.width - window_width) / 2,
                           (monitor_dimension.height - window_height) / 2 - 75,
                           window_width,
                           window_height,
                           (HWND)NULL,
                           (HMENU)NULL,
                           hInstance,
                           (LPVOID)NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

I get the result using `SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, RGB(255, 0, 0), 0, LWA_COLORKEY);` **without manifest** and the clicks don't pass through.
The following code adapted from [SetLayeredWindowAttributes() causes mouse clicks to go through after minimizing window | WinAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74494352/setlayeredwindowattributes-causes-mouse-clicks-to-go-through-after-minimizing).

```
// WindowsProject2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "framework.h"
#include "WindowsProject2.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT2, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT2));

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WINDOWSPROJECT2));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0));
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT2);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE: Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, RGB(255, 0, 0), 0 /*doesn't matter*/, LWA_COLORKEY);
        HWND hbutton = CreateWindowExA(0,
            "BUTTON",
            "X",
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_FLAT,
            10,
            10,
            100,
            100,
            hWnd,
            (HMENU)NULL,
            NULL,
            (LPVOID)NULL);
        /*HWND hbackground = CreateWindowEx(0,
            L"STATIC",
            NULL,
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_BITMAP,
            0,
            0,
            600,
            400,
            hWnd,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            (LPVOID)NULL);
        setImage(hbackground, L"test.bmp", 600, 400);*/
        //SetWindowLong(hbackground, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hbackground, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
        //SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hbackground, 0, (255 * 50) / 100, LWA_ALPHA);
    }
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this doesn't allow me to paint one part of the window translucent while keeping the other part opaque right?. It only displays the button. Also the reason I am using a manifest file is because that's the way it supports extended layers on child windows.

Comment: [UpdateLayeredWindow always updates the entire window. To update part of a window, use the traditional WM_PAINT and set the blend value using SetLayeredWindowAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-updatelayeredwindow#remarks). Using WM_PAINT to paint.